Gradle daemon taking too long for resolving dependencies
I ran cordova build android but the command got stuck on:
> root project > Resolve files of configuration ':classpath' > bundletool-1.15.
> root project > Resolve files of configuration ':classpath' > gradle-8.3.0.jar
> root project > Resolve files of configuration ':classpath' > kotlin-compiler-

I tried changing Gradle version, clearing cache of the Gradle, reinstalling Gradle, changing JDK version and reinstalling Cordova but this issue still occurs. The command is simply taking too long to run and never terminating. What is the issue?
